# Find historical data in Azure DevOps for Work Items to define development metrics

Tags: azure-devops, metrics, project-management, agile, agile-project-management

In order to find some Agile Metrix of the project in Azure DevOps (ADO) from last month or from last 2 sprints, I was trying to Query data from ADO like:

- When a user story was committed and reach to done state?
- How long a developer took on a user story before it turned to QA?
- How much time QA took after receiving it from Dev?
- How many Dev and QA have worked on a user story and how long? Compare that number with the estimated time given at the time if sprint planning.
- How many time a user story been returned back to Dev for any reason like not fulling Acceptance Criteria, etc?
  ...

In ADO, I can query the current data, however, there is no way to find historical data from **State Graph**, **History**, **Discussion**!!! I want to find out if the User Story has gone through multiple resources, how much time each of them have spend on that!

Can someone please give me some direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Azure Devops connector for Power BI?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer ? How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the historical data using Analytics [Odata API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/quick-ref?view=azure-devops). For below example using [WorkItemRevisions entity set to load all the revisions for a given work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/analytics-recipes?view=azure-devops#retrieve-work-item-history)

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//WorkItemRevisions?
  $filter=WorkItemId eq {Id}
  &$select=WorkItemId, Title, State
```

Then You can [Run the OData query from Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/odataquery-connect?view=azure-devops) to create a PowerBI report. Also see document [Power BI integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops). Please check example [Calculate time-in-state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-timeinstate-report?view=azure-devops).

You can also use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get historical data of a workitem. See below:

[Revisions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

[Comments - Get Comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/get%20comments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

[Updates - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Answer (score 0):

For querying historical data of single workitem you can use this chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/azure-devops-workitem-inf/ociekhbkajgbjdenikmandhpjlekckee.

There you can see changes of any field, and also you can see how many time the field was in particular state.